# selectlist fails when accessing dataTextField

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, selectlist

I am trying to create a Dropdownlist for a list of the following class:

```
public class PrimulaPositionViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Name { get; set; }
}
```

and in my cshtml view i call the dropdownlist like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Position", new SelectList(Model.Positions, "Id", "Name['sv']", 
guise.PrimulaPositionId))
```

My issue is that *"Name['sv']"* doesn't get the value held in the dictionary and instead makes the program throw an error. If i were to just write *Name* then i would get an error but the dropdownlist simply outputs system.gen...... to represent the dictionary.

so i am wondering how i can access the Name["sv"] value when i am creating the SelectList in the view.

Comment: this looks strange, it may depend on the dataTextField string supporting accessing a Dictionary field or not. Have you tried `"Name[\"sv\"]"` or `"Name[sv]"`?. If neither of those works, there is a high chance that accessing Dictionary field is not supported. You can however always project your own list of `SelectListItem`, e.g: `Model.Positions.Select(e => new SelectListItem(e.Name["sv"], e.Id.ToString(), e.Id == guise.PrimulaPositionId))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We usually put propertyName as dataTextField in SelectListItem.
If you want to use dictionary,you can use `<select></select>`,and put Id and Name['sv'] into option in foreach:

```
<select>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Positions)
        {
            if (item.Id == guise.PrimulaPositionId)
            {
                <option id="@item.Id" selected>@item.Name["sv"]</option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option id="@item.Id">@item.Name["sv"]</option>
            }

        }
    </select>
```